# Android SDK WebView call Activity

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to launch an Activity when clicking a link inside a WebView component.

My Webview is loaded inside `Main.java` and I would like to launch `SubActivity.java` when clicking a link inside the Website which is in `Main.java`?

Also, how can I pass parameters to this activity?

**Example**: `inspection://Project/1`

"Inspection" is the name of my application, `inspection` is the Activity I would like to launch and `1` is the ID I would like to have.

Comment: You should also take a look at this article [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Answer (score 12):

You could use WebView's [addJavaScriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String)) to allow JavaScript to control your application (in this case, to allow JavaScript to fire an Intent when a link is clicked).

To do this you need to pass a class instance to bind to JavaScript, this could be something like the following:

```
private final class JsInterface {
      public void launchIntent(final String payload) {
         Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // use the payload if you want, attach as an extra, switch destination, etc.
               Activity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this, SomeOtherActivity.class));
            }
         });
      }
   }
```

Then you add that to the WebView with something along these lines:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(js, "Android");
```

Then in JavaScript from the WebView you just use your new "Android" object's "launchIntent" method.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to override the URL loading of the web view and pick up the click you want to launch the new activity. Check out the use of a subclassed WebViewClient in the docs:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Another option is to bind your activity to a custom URL scheme. It's pretty common in doing client side OAuth, frequently through the browser instead of a WebView, but it should work similarly enough. There's a full example here:

[https://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth](https://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth/blob/eb6c038f87536c633f040acd7a7df209664928ec/src/com/example/bloa/OAUTH.java)

Which shows how to bind the url scheme handler as well as handling getting launched via the Intent it generates (see onResume() in OAUTH.java).

Answer (score 0):

First Add javascript method on your webpage's button onclick()
The function defined below..

```
function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    AndroidFunction.showToast(toast);
}
```

Android Code is here for javascript Interface..

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;
     private Activity activity;

        public MyJavaScriptInterface(Activity activiy) {
            this.activity = activiy;
        }
 @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast){
  Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Subactivity.class);

  i.putExtra("data", "tosecondActivity");
 startActivity(i);
```

}