# Android Web View to Android Java Activity Class

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

is it possible to make a html button that when I click, it will go to my android activity class.
Just like using Intent when I view Activity to another Activity

anyone have a thoughts?

my JsInteface class change into this

```
 public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }


    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(mContext, echos.class); 
        mContext.startActivity(mainIntent); 

    }

}
```

Comment: try using java script to do that and pemission for that web view search for java script bridge in android

Comment: Check this link . http://stackoverflow.com/a/4846692/614807

Comment: how can i call it in javascript?

Comment: just call the method from java script on click

Comment: but the code from the link above doesn't working for me

Comment: @user1635137 see the answer below i hope you ll get an idea its for a toast change it to whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

in java script

```
   <input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    Android.showToast(toast);
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: I already tried this one. But still don't have an Idea how to change the Toast method into Intent method

Comment: just change the code  Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
to   Intent mainIntent = new Intent(yourcontext, yheclass you want to go.class);
 youractivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

Comment: should I change this one? public void showToast(String toast)

Comment: no need as its just the name of the function called from java script if you cahange that change the function name in java script too

Comment: can you please take a look at my edited question above. because it still not working

Comment: change the JavaScriptInterface.this.startActivity(mainIntent); to mContext.startActivity(mainIntent); as JavaScriptInterface is not an activity

Comment: I already change it into mContext but still not showing the echos.class

Comment: no there is no error. It just not showing the class that I declared in my Intent

Comment: try to run in the ui thread private final class JsInterface {
      public void launchIntent(final String payload) {
         Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // use the payload if you want, attach as an extra, switch destination, etc.
               Activity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this, SomeOtherActivity.class));
            }
         });
      }
   }

Comment: can you please edit it to codes format? its very hard to read

Comment: check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846296/android-sdk-webview-call-activity/4846692#4846692 change the function name and use it