# How to call an app mobile via web view?

Tags: android, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

is there a solution to call a mobile app via a link in a web page(my web page is a web view in a mobile app). For example, I want to call facebook app when tap on a link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SDK WebView call Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846296/android-sdk-webview-call-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `<intent-filter>`. See [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser).

For the simplest case, you need to add something like this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="your-url-.com"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an Intent filter in Manifest file like this -

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="www.tamrakar.in"
        android:path="/test"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Hope this helps.